# React Material UI Syntax with Props Explained

Tags: reactjs

I understand the basic of react code such as passing data to child component and passing data back to parent with props. I encountered this code below from [React Material UI](https://material-ui.com/demos/progress/) which is abit confusing. Was hoping to get some explanation.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress';
import purple from '@material-ui/core/colors/purple';

const styles = theme => ({
  progress: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
  },
});

function CircularIndeterminate(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <CircularProgress className={classes.progress} />
      <CircularProgress className={classes.progress} size={50} />
      <CircularProgress className={classes.progress} color="secondary" />
      <CircularProgress className={classes.progress} style={{ color: purple[500] }} thickness={7} />
    </div>
  );
}

CircularIndeterminate.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(CircularIndeterminate);
```

Here is what I understand.

1.The component takes in props so I can pass data down to this child component and before render it will extract the classes property from props.classes.

2.There  is a styles function that takes in a theme variable and returns an object progress which has some styling which is used by classes.progress

3.withStyle is some sort of higher order component.

But with this knowledge, this code is abit confusing.

How come the code can do classes.progress, why does classes variable have anything to do with the progress style

What is the purpose of

```
CircularIndeterminate.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

classes variable that is that is passed in as a prop is an object with progress being one of its key. The classes object might look like

```
classes = {
   progress: 'half'
}
```

Now the value of classes.progress which in the above classes object is `half` is assigned as a className prop to the CircularProgress component.

Regarding

```
CircularIndeterminate.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

The above syntax is to add typechecking capabilities to your component. React has some built-in typechecking abilities. To run typechecking on the props for a component, you can assign the special `propTypes` property.

In your case, it means that the `CircularIndeterminate` expects a prop `classes` which is of type `object` and is a Required prop.

To read more about PropTypes, please visit **[the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)**